# na.rm = T treatment by ggplot2's geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, na.rm

I am trying to understand how ggplot2's geom_bar treats NAs.
The help file says:

```
library(ggplot2)
?geom_bar
```

na.rm: If FALSE, the default, missing values are removed with a warning. If TRUE, missing values are silently removed.

I am trying it out:

```
md <- data.frame(a = c(letters[1:5], letters[1:4], letters[1:3], rep(NA, 3)))
str(md); levels(md$a)

ggplot(data = md, mapping = aes(x = a)) +
  geom_bar(na.rm = F)
```

It runs without warnings and generates counts for each factor level AS WELL AS the NAs. Makes sense.

Now, I don't want the NAs to be counted. So, I run:

```
ggplot(data = md, mapping = aes(x = a)) +
  geom_bar(na.rm = T)
```

But I still have NAs in the picture. Why?
What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify: my question is not about "who could I exclude NAs from being counted" - I know how to do that.
My question is: Why na.rm = T is not working for geom_bar in this case?

Answer (score -1):

Its a bug that [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) doses not remove *the character case*. It's discussed [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1584).